# Having problems with Sql To Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have a sql query set up:

```
select
  sm.coddeposito as coddeposito,
  rd.codart as codart,
  ast.codsottotipo as codsottotipo,
  ast.descrizionesottotipo as descrizionesottotipo,
  sum(sm.GIACENZA * sm.QTA1UM) as giacenza1,
  sum(sm.GIACENZA2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as giacenza2,
  sum(sm.ordinato * sm.QTA1UM) as ordinato1,
  sum(sm.ordinato2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as ordinato2,
  sum(sm.impegnato * sm.QTA1UM) as impegnato1,
  sum(sm.impegnato2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as impegnato2
from Programmi.dbo.SAN_STORICOMAG as sm
join programmi.dbo.san_righedocumenti 
  as rd on sm.IDTESTA = rd.idtesta and sm.rigadoc = rd.idriga
join programmi.dbo.SAN_EXTRARIGHEDOC 
  as erd on rd.idtesta = erd.idtesta and rd.idriga = erd.idriga 
join programmi.dbo.tk_tab_anasottotipi 
  as ast on erd.tk_codsottotipo = ast.CODSOTTOTIPO
where sm.codart like '%RTM%' 
  and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo <> '' 
  and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo is not null
group by 
  sm.coddeposito, 
  rd.codart,  
  ast.codsottotipo, 
  ast.descrizionesottotipo
order by 
  sm.coddeposito, 
  rd.codart,  
  ast.codsottotipo, 
  ast.descrizionesottotipo
```

I found a way to do a group by statement but it does not work like my SQL one does.
That is my Linq query:

```
from sm in db.SAN_STORICOMAG
from rd in 
  db.SAN_RIGHEDOCUMENTI.Where(x => x.IDTESTA.Equals(sm.IDTESTA ?? 0) 
  && x.IDRIGA.Equals(sm.RIGADOC ?? 0))
from erd in 
  db.SAN_EXTRARIGHEDOC.Where(x => x.IDTESTA.Equals(rd.IDTESTA) 
  && x.IDRIGA.Equals(rd.IDRIGA))
from ast in 
  db.TK_TAB_ANASOTTOTIPI.Where(x => x.CODSOTTOTIPO.Equals(erd.Tk_CodSottotipo))
where sm.CODART.Contains("RTM")
  && erd.Tk_CodSottotipo != string.Empty
  && erd.Tk_CodSottotipo != null
orderby 
  sm.CODDEPOSITO, 
  rd.CODART, 
  ast.CODSOTTOTIPO, 
  ast.DESCRIZIONESOTTOTIPO
group new Result
{
  CODDEPOSITO = sm.CODDEPOSITO,
  CODART = rd.CODART,
  DESCRIZIONEART = rd.DESCRIZIONEART,
  CODSOTTOTIPO = ast.CODSOTTOTIPO,
  DESCRIZIONESOTTOTIPO = ast.DESCRIZIONESOTTOTIPO,
  GIACENZA1 = (sm.GIACENZA * sm.QTA1UM) ?? 0,
  GIACENZA2 = (sm.GIACENZA2UM * sm.QTA2UM) ?? 0
}
by new
{
  sm.CODDEPOSITO,
  rd.CODART,
  ast.CODSOTTOTIPO,
  ast.DESCRIZIONESOTTOTIPO
}
into x
from xx in x
select xx
```

Another problem is that with this LINQ query, i can't access the members inside it, after the group by declaration.

Comment: When your linq has run does it have a count of members? "into x
from xx in x" sounds like a bad bit of naming going on there.. What happens if you give your structure you're creating that first bit of linq names rather than just new {} ? so new { Coddepostio=sm.CODDEPOSTIO ..etc}

Comment: Honestly with complex queries (and this one is not too complex by any means) it is usually much easier to create a SQL View and then create a EF model in c# based on that Sql View. This will also allow you to more easily tweak the sql as you see fit without having to revisit the Linq query in c# to see what it produces in Sql.

Comment: Are you missing the "left outer join"?  See following : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to propose a different solution (so not addressing the Linq statement directly). With more complex queries (and this one is not too complex by any means) it is usually better to create a SQL View and then create a EF model in c# based on that Sql View. This will also allow you to more easily tweak the sql as you see fit without having to revisit the Linq query in c# to see what it produces in Sql. The end result in sql (the translation between the linq query and the produced sql statement) can vary depending on the ORM you are using where as a custom sql view will always be static (it stays the way you defined it).

Create your view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyCustomView
AS
select
  sm.coddeposito as coddeposito,
  rd.codart as codart,
  ast.codsottotipo as codsottotipo,
  ast.descrizionesottotipo as descrizionesottotipo,
  sum(sm.GIACENZA * sm.QTA1UM) as giacenza1,
  sum(sm.GIACENZA2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as giacenza2,
  sum(sm.ordinato * sm.QTA1UM) as ordinato1,
  sum(sm.ordinato2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as ordinato2,
  sum(sm.impegnato * sm.QTA1UM) as impegnato1,
  sum(sm.impegnato2UM * sm.QTA2UM) as impegnato2
from Programmi.dbo.SAN_STORICOMAG as sm
join programmi.dbo.san_righedocumenti 
  as rd on sm.IDTESTA = rd.idtesta and sm.rigadoc = rd.idriga
join programmi.dbo.SAN_EXTRARIGHEDOC 
  as erd on rd.idtesta = erd.idtesta and rd.idriga = erd.idriga 
join programmi.dbo.tk_tab_anasottotipi 
  as ast on erd.tk_codsottotipo = ast.CODSOTTOTIPO
where sm.codart like '%RTM%' 
  and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo <> '' 
  and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo is not null
group by 
  sm.coddeposito, 
  rd.codart,  
  ast.codsottotipo, 
  ast.descrizionesottotipo
order by 
  sm.coddeposito, 
  rd.codart,  
  ast.codsottotipo, 
  ast.descrizionesottotipo
```

Your c# Model *(I am guess at your types here)*:

```
public class MyModel {
    public object coddeposito { get; set; }
    public object codart { get; set; }
    public object codsottotipo { get; set; }
    public object descrizionesottotipo { get; set; }
    public int giacenza1 { get; set; }
    public int giacenza2 { get; set; }
    public int ordinato1 { get; set; }
    public int ordinato2 { get; set; }
    public int impegnato1 { get; set; }
    public int impegnato2 { get; set; }
}
```

You did not mention if this is Linq or EF or some other ORM but your next step is to map this model the same way you did with your other models in the ORM you are using.

Also you can remove some of the filters in the `WHERE` clause if you know these will be dynamic. You can then still apply them in your Linq code as needed.

**Disclaimer**
I did not check your query for accuracy or efficiency so if there are mistakes or better ways of producing the joins I did not look for them.

Comment: Thank you igor! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it:

```
from sm in Programmi.dbo.SAN_STORICOMAG
join rd in programmi.dbo.san_righedocumenti 
    on new { condition1 = sm.IDTESTA, condition2 = sm.rigadoc } 
    equals new { condition1 = rd.idtesta, condition2 = rd.idriga }
join erd in programmi.dbo.SAN_EXTRARIGHEDOC 
    on new { condition1 = rd.idtesta, condition2 = rd.idriga } 
    equals new { condition1 = erd.idtesta, condition2 = erd.idriga }
join ast in programmi.dbo.tk_tab_anasottotipi 
    on erd.tk_codsottotipo 
    equals ast.CODSOTTOTIPO
where sm.codart.Contains("RTM")
and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo <> '' 
and erd.Tk_CodSottotipo != null
group new { 
    Giacenza = sm.GIACENZA, 
    Qta1um = sm.QTA1UM, 
    Giacenza2um = sm.GIACENZA2UM, 
    Qta2um = sm.QTA2UM,
    Ordinato = sm.ordinato,
    Ordinato2UM = sm.ordinato2UM,
    Impegnato = sm.impegnato,
    Impegnato2UM = sm.impegnato2UM
} 
by new { 
    Coddeposito = sm.coddeposito, 
    Codart = rd.codart, 
    Codsottotipo = ast.codsottotipo, 
    Descrizionesottotipo = ast.descrizionesottotipo 
} into g
order by g.Key.Coddeposito, g.Key.Codart, g.Key.Codsottotipo, g.Key.Descrizionesottotipo
select new 
{ 
    coddeposito = g.Key.Coddeposito, 
    codart = g.Key.Codart, 
    codsottotipo = g.Key.Codsottotipo, 
    descrizionesottotipo  = g.Key.Descrizionesottotipo, 
    giacenza1 = g.Sum(p => p.Giacenza * p.Qta1um),
    giacenza2 = g.Sum(p => p.Giacenza2um * p.Qta2um),
    ordinato1 = g.Sum(p => p.Ordinato * p.Qta1um),
    ordinato2UM = g.Sum(p => p.Ordinato2UM * p.Qta2um),
    impegnato1 = g.Sum(p => p.Impegnato * p.Qta1um),
    impegnato2 = g.Sum(p => p.Impegnato2UM * p.Qta2um)
}
```